# Do tags have dates?

Tags: tags

I've created something using reverse tags – when something isn't tagged, it's flagged up to say "Hey! This post hasn't been checked yet!"

Now i'm wondering, is there a way to get the last tag created?

Do tags have modified / created dates? Is there a way of getting around this if they haven't?

The user case I have is security patches for a CMS and I have a team who are documenting everything about it. I want them to create a new tag for the patch, then have a notice display saying "New patch available"

Anyone crossed anything like this before?

Comment: Tags don't have dates. However, you can save this data in the new term meta table when you create new tags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following @PieterGoosen's (credit due) train of thought hook onto the following:

```
function update_term_timestamps($term_id) {

    switch( current_filter() ) {
        case 'created_term':
            update_term_meta($term_id, '_term_created_at', current_time('mysql', true));
        break;
        case 'edited_term':
            update_term_meta($term_id, '_term_edited_at', current_time('mysql', true));
        break;
    }

}

add_action('created_term', 'update_term_timestamps');
add_action('edited_term', 'update_term_timestamps');
```

Now the meta data is accessible with:

```
//for created timestamp...
$timestamp = get_term_meta($term_id, '_term_created_at', true);

//for edited timestamp...
$timestamp = get_term_meta($term_id, '_term_edited_at', true);
```

Comment: ... I see a popular plugin in the making here ;-)

Comment: Looking very promising :D

Comment: `_term_last_mod_author_id` would be handy too.

Comment: @toscho good idea... sketching out a prototype.

Comment: @userabuser Imagine being able to query these dates too

Comment: @AndrewLazarus on my list too... I'll post back to this thread with a link to the repository when ready.

Comment: @userabuser How's the idea coming along?

Comment: I've written the plugin actually, just wont get around to pushing it up to a repo until tomorrow or Thursday.